# Remove log message in openerp

Tags: odoo

How to remove procurement exception log message in openerp? for example[image]

Here I just dont want to show the procurement exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.
inherit the function `_check_make_to_stock_product()` from the procurement and then search the `'res.log'` model with domain `[('res_model','=',self._name),('res_id','='our_procurement_id,)]`
Then Unlink it. Thats it :)